# strange behavior for variable "name" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and i have tried one example today, can someone help me to explain why?

all test are done on console panel from Chrome:

```
var greetingHello = "Hello";
var name = prompt("please enter your name");
document.write(greetingHello + " " + name + "<br>");

var name = new Array("name1","name2","name3");
document.write(name[0]);
```

The result is `n`

But if i change the second "name" variable from "name" to "myName", and executed myName[0]

the result is "name1"

Why is it so strange?

Comment: Don't you have a global variable or a superior scope variable with the `name`?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vG349/

Comment: `The result is n`. Not it's not.

Comment: @j08691 that is wrapped in an _onload_, see http://jsfiddle.net/D54mG/

Comment: @Felipe Oriani I have only this small piece of code, i do not think i have anywhere global variable for it

Answer (score 6):

Your problem comes from the conflict with *String* [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name), when you try to set `name` in the global namespace, you're really invoking a setter which calls *toString* and `["name1","name2"].toString()[0] === "n"`.

This behaviour may differ across different browsers depending on the implementation of their `var`.

Comment: `name` is protected by `var`. There should be no conflict.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi try it in _Chrome_

Comment: +1, successfully reproduced this using Opera 20. Also, `var myName = new Array("name1", "name2"); window.myName;` will print the array in the console.

Comment: @Paul, j08691's fiddle gives the expected result in Chrome. However, I suspect that's because the fiddle doesn't parse `var name = ...` in the global scope. I will double-check.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's wrapped in the _onload_, see http://jsfiddle.net/D54mG/

Comment: Yup, I double-checked, and Chrome's behavior is indeed what you describe. Firefox still allocates a new `name` variable, even in the global scope. Now I wonder which one is right :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Consider `var document = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();` and then tell me which one is right.

Comment: @Paul, if I had to decide (fortunately, I don't), I would say `var` should never be ignored for global names. It is always possible to omit `var` (or say `window.document`) if you want to do that.

Comment: I can not fully understand what you are talking about, but one thing is sure that the problem is only existing on Chrome. I do not have problem with another browsers. Can someone make a conclusion at the end to help me understand it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you :)